# Rancher add internal CA to connect to other systems

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate, rancher, ca

TL;DR: How can I make a internal root CA known to Rancher when the Rancher SSL cert is not signed by it, but other external systems (like OIDC provider) are?

I have a running Rancher in version `v2.6.3` on one of my VMs as a Docker container. It uses a SSL certificate signed by DigiCert, as I'm using it to manage clusters outside of my own network. The Web UI login is only used from within my network. I use an OIDC client in Keycloak for it. Since this Keycloak is (and should stay) only accessible from my internal network it has a certificate signed by my internal CA.

To get this working I needed to make the root CA known to Rancher. So I mounted it to the container at `/etc/rancher/ssl/cacerts.pem` alongside my DigiCert-signed certificate and key (`SSL_CERT_DIR` is set to `/etc/rancher/ssl`).

After doing that I could successfully configure OIDC auth with my internal Keycloak. Before adding the root CA, I got a certificate error when Rancher tried to read `https://<KEYCLOAK REALM AUTH URL>/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

Now Rancher is adding this root CA certificate to the `kubeconfig` files the users can download from the UI to access their clusters. Which then results in a certificate error when they want to access the cluster with `kubectl`. I could now tell everyone to just remove the `certificate-authority-data` when they download their config. But it feels like - even though it is working - that this is not the correct way to make the certificate known to Rancher. If I understand the documentation and the *result* described here correctly, the file `/etc/rancher/ssl/cacerts.pem` should only be used in case your Rancher uses a certificate signed by a non-public CA.

Is there another way to make my internal CA known to Rancher? Unfortunately I could only find [this article](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/resources/custom-ca-root-certificate/) in the documentation which I followed to the result above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I found something in the [Rancher Helm Chart Options](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/installation/install-rancher-on-k8s/chart-options/) about *Additional Trusted CAs*. Which lead me to the Helm chart where I found this block in the [Deployment](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/blob/release/v2.6/chart/templates/deployment.yaml):

```yaml
{{- if .Values.additionalTrustedCAs }}
- mountPath: /etc/pki/trust/anchors/ca-additional.pem
  name: tls-ca-additional-volume
  subPath: ca-additional.pem
  readOnly: true
- mountPath: /etc/rancher/ssl/ca-additional.pem
  name: tls-ca-additional-volume
  subPath: ca-additional.pem
  readOnly: true
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.privateCA }}
# Pass CA cert into rancher for private CA
- mountPath: /etc/rancher/ssl/cacerts.pem
  name: tls-ca-volume
  subPath: cacerts.pem
  readOnly: true
{{- end }}
```

Apparently adding additional CA certs to the trust store is as easy as mounting the CAs to `/etc/rancher/ssl/ca-additional.pem` and `/etc/pki/trust/anchors/ca-additional.pem`.

Tried it already and it is working like a charm! OIDC login works and when I download a `kubeconfig` the `certificate-authority-data` is not set.